# How to Localize UWP DirectX C++?

Tags: c++, uwp, directx

I have latest Visual C++ 17 (15.9.4), and started with the UWP directX C++ Template (without XAML).

When i run that, it works. It shows a multi colored spinning cube, in a window, or fullscreen if i fullscreen it, and also shows the FPS number at the botom right of the screen.

Now i want to add localization to that, and i went there:

[Localize strings in your UI and app package manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest)

So i Added those 2 lines from that example:

```
auto resourceLoader = Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::ResourceLoader::GetForCurrentView();
this->myXAMLTextBlockElement->Text = resourceLoader->GetString("Farewell");
```

in my code like this:

```
void App::Run()
{
    auto resourceLoader = Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::ResourceLoader::GetForCurrentView();
    auto myText = resourceLoader->GetString("Farewell");

    while (!m_windowClosed)
    {
        if (m_windowVisible)
        {
            CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Dispatcher->ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption::ProcessAllIfPresent);

            m_main->Update();

            if (m_main->Render())
            {
                m_deviceResources->Present();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()->Dispatcher->ProcessEvents(CoreProcessEventsOption::ProcessOneAndAllPending);
        }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work, i get an exception in the first line of that code, saying that it doesn't find the resourcemap. 
I did all what they said: created a "Strings" directory, and in there an "en-US" directory, and in there a Resources.resw file having the "Farewell" string set to "bye bye !".

The exception it throws:

```
Exception levée à 0x747D1812 dans App9.exe : exception Microsoft C++ : 
Platform::COMException ^ à l'emplacement de mémoire 0x02CDF49C. 
HRESULT:0x80073B1F ResourceMap introuvable.
Informations WinRT : ResourceMap introuvable.
```

Comment: Set your app's language to be en-US, because it looks like it's the problem. You might try to load resources for different language (the one your system is using), instead the one you've created.

Comment: I did that, so that's not the problem.

Comment: You should take a look at the [NLSAndLocalization](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples/System/NLSAndLocalizationUWP) sample on GitHub.

Comment: I looked at that, and this is horrible. Can only be much easier and shorter than that!

Comment: Could you share a mini sample that could reproduce this issue ?

Comment: This IS a mini example, i started by using the directX UWP Template (without XAML), changed nothing there, and just Added those 2 lines of code at the top of App::Run()

Comment: Please check the **Windows Display Language** in setting page.

Comment: It is French, but it should still work, because i have set the language in the Package.appxmanifest to en-US. Also to be sure it's not that, i also have created an "fr-FR" directory in the Strings directory, with the same Resources.resw file.

Comment: Have you tried clean your project then rebuild it ?

Comment: Yes, and i just recreated the project, copied the Strings directory to every possible place (the app main directory, the debug directory, and another one). Took UWP C++ DirectX project (the one without XAML), i put those 2 lines i described above,  and same…  it just ends with an exception. I have edited the main post to add that exception at the end.

Comment: It looks a bug, Could share a sample for me, I will report this.

Comment: project shared on Onedrive:  https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aj7wxGmZTdftgYYySUIwG7NxWTX47w

Comment: Any update ?  i still Don't know how to localize my game. It seems to work on projects using XAML and C++ directX11,  but not on a project using the directX11 C++ Visual Studio Template.

Comment: I FOUND THe PROBLEM !   I'm so sorry,  i named my resw file Resource.resw,  instead of Resources.resw .  Now that i Added that 's' it works !